# Where does Oracle DBCA come in?

Tags: database, oracle, installation

I'm planning to play around with Oracle Business Intelligence (for fun). I have access to a number of Oracle products, and may have gone overboard installing them all (quite possibly more than I need).

Problem is I'm not too sure how all the different Oracle components fit together, but I think I am still missing something, a crucial part - DBCA.

All the online help material I can find says use DBCA to create a database - but I don't seem to have DBCA anywhere.

What I do have installed is:

- Oracle - OraClient11g_home1
- Oracle - OraDb11g_home1
- Oracle Business Intelligence
- Oracle Weblogic

Does Oracle have a separate Database Server that is not included in the above? (Like MS SQL Server)

I'll note that I am completely new to Oracle and may be missing something very simple, so any help would be appreciated.

I'm looking for an answer that can lead me to how I can install DBCA and create my database but extra kudos for any additional *brief* information on how these Oracle *building* blocks work independently and together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBCA is the database configuration assistant.  It is a wizard used to create a database and should be instaled during the server install.  If you are testing you just want to create a database as part of the server insall and ignore dbca.

Answer (score 1):

`Oracle - OraDb11g_home1` **is** the database (most probably at least - given then Oracle naming conventions). DBCA was called as part of the installation process.

Note that a "database" in Oracle terms is something completely different than a "database" in MS SQL Server. A SQL Server "database" is closer to an Oracle schema.